# how to check the results of individual Naive Bayes predictions?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I have made a Naive Bayes model for prediction. all went well and can predict even if only for one input only. I want to predict a data and save all the results of the prediction to a csv file. but when I try it, I get an error message like the picture below.
this picture shows how I was looping my data and also the error that appears.

Code:

```
# load previously saved classifier and vectorizer
vectorizer, classifer = load()
print('\nPerform a test')      
df = pd.read_csv('tweet_BARU.csv') #read the CSV file
data_label = df["full_text"]

tweet_pred = []
tweet_input = data_label
for sentence in data_label:
    tweet_input_transformed = vectorizer.transform(sentence)
    prediction = classifer.predict(tweet_input_transformed)
    tweet_pred = 0
    if (prediction=='neutral'):
        tweet_pred.append('neutral')
    elif (prediction=='positive'):
        tweet_pred.append('positive')
    else:
        tweet_pred.append('negative')
```

error :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-227d63cffdf9> in <module>()
     11     prediction = classifer.predict(tweet_input_transformed)
     12     tweet_pred = 0
---> 13     if (prediction=='neutral'):
     14         tweet_pred.append('neutral')
     15     elif (prediction=='positive'):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

where did i make a mistake?
can anyone solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please post which is the shape of the prediction variable?

Comment: Actually, if the `if-else` here was indeed working, it would be completely unnecessary - a simple assignment `tweet_pred = prediction` would do the job (why the `tweet_pred = 0` in the loop?)

Answer (score 1):

maybe it's because I don't understand using python yet. actually I don't need to do a loop because it's already automatically looping every data.

code :

```
tweet_input_transformed = vectorizer.transform(data_label)
prediction = classifer.predict(tweet_input_transformed)

results = pd.DataFrame({
        "Labeled Data" : data_label,
        "Label" : prediction
        })
results.to_csv("Hasil_NBC.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: Good job...! ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` statement you are trying to compare the value of a `prediction` variable with a string. This doesn't make sense, because the type of `prediction` variable should be `ndarray` - this is a return type of a `predict()` method of a Naive Bayes classifier in scikit-learn.

Also, later in your code you are tring to append a string to an integer (`tweet_pred`, which was redefined in a for-loop). This will not work either.

To save the contents of `prediction` in a file, one value per line, you can do the following:

```
prediction = classifer.predict(tweet_input_transformed)
with open("\path\to\a\file.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(prediction))
```

Comment: but when I enter only one data the prediction process can work. where I use the same code for if else.

Comment: Do you have a solution to enter the prediction results into a file?

Comment: Can you show the contents of a `prediction` variable?